# Did my site get hacked?

Tags: joomla-3.x, security

I am seeing this error on front page of one of my website

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<
```

Some code has been hidden for security* but the source of that error is index.php. On examining my index.php i see a line of code referncing index_old.php. The code on the that file is as shown

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
       $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

       $logfilename1=dirname(__FILE__).'/htaccess.log';

       $fp2=fopen($logfilename1,"a");

       fwrite($fp2,$ip);

       fwrite($fp2," ".$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]."    ".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]); 

       fwrite($fp2," ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

       fwrite($fp2," ".strftime('%c')."\r\n");

       fclose($fp2);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am cracking my head to find out if the site has been infiltrated or injected with suspicious scripts. Could anyone help me figure out this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of have have posted numerous answers on Joomla Stack Exchange about what to to in case of a site being hacked.

My suggestion first would be to delete the `index_old.php` file, then remove the reference to this file in the `index.php`.

**Then have a read of these:**

- [What to do if my Joomla website got hacked](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-to-do-if-my-joomla-website-got-hacked)
- [Site gets hacked after admin is created](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16003/site-gets-hacked-and-everytime-a-new-user-is-created-with-admin-rights)
- [Try to fix a hacked site](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15027/trying-to-fix-hacked-site)

**A quick summary:**

- Update Joomla to latest version (*currently 3.5.1*)
- Update ALL extensions to their latest version
- Change your password for the hosting control panel, FTP and Joomla super user
- Ensure **chmod** permissions for is **755** for directories and **644** for files

Comment: Seems like i cannot get around this problem. Again i am seeing this error